# opt/lampp/htdocs cant be accessed

Tags: 13.04, lamp, xampp

First, im new on ubuntu so please bear with me.

Im using ubuntu 13.04 and i just installed lampp. Now i want to copy a file to `opt/lampp/htdocs`. I also cant create new folder and documents in this location.

When i see the properties of a file, it said "you are not the owner, bla bla", and i cant edit the "Access" drop down list. What is going on? What should i do?

Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I googled a little about it, but why 777?

Comment: Sorry but it should be 775, if i use 777 then i cant access the PHP files. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Hey, but i cant copy-paste when using 775, is there any other way so ALL thing is working than by changing the chmod manually? :D